# Server 2012 Essentials - Gray Screen unable to log in

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a new Server 2012 Essentials installation that was installed on XMAS Eve. Everything had been in working order when I left for a 12 day break..

On return I find that I cannot log into the server locally or via remote desktop. On reboot all I get is a gray screen with nothing else, ALT-CTRL-DEL has not effect.. When connecting via RDP I enter my account details then get the Gray/Black Screen and nothing else..

Now the server is running and I can login and use our Database that uses the SQL instance from a client machine..

I can access the files shares but simply cannot log in to make any changes to the server settings or to backup the Database...

Any Help Appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I would begin with starting the server up in Safe-Mode and see if that helps in getting you into the computer. If that gets you into the computer have a look at the driver for your graphics card and look at event viewer for any hint to what is going on. Then I would also run a `sfc /scannow` just for good measures.